# Error en mis ciclos While

Tags: matlab

Estoy realizando un sistema de una tienda "virtual" en matlab y los ciclos while no se estan respetando. Estoy haciendo ciclos anidados de tal forma que se mantenga dentro del bloque indicado hasta que se "rompa" ese while y salga a su while padre.
Sin embargo en vez de escalar los ciclos while de manera jerarquica mi programa salta hasta el while principal (al que anida a todos los demas). 
Ya busque en internet como realizar anidaciones de while en matlab pero no hay informacion al respecto.

¿Cuál seria la forma de implementar una solucion para que escale los cilos while de manera jerarquica?

Este es el codigo:

```
 %Arreglo de cadenas(string)
 %En cada fila tenemos los valores [Nombre Usuario | Correo | Contrasena]
 usuariosInfo = ["Jhon" "adidas01@gmail.com.mx", "admin";
                "Ricky" "adidas02@gmail.com.mx", "admin";
                "Frank" "adidas03@gmail.com.mx", "admin";];

 loopMain = true;
 loopHome = true;
 loopCalidad = true;

 recibo =["Producto", "Precio"];
 totalCompra = 0;

 while loopMain == true  
    fprintf('\nBienvenido a Adidas.com:\n');
    email = input('Escribe tu email:  ','s');
    contra = input('Escribe tu contrasena:  ','s');



    %ismember busca los valores de email y contrasena dentro de usuariosInfo
    emailMatch = ismember(email, usuariosInfo);
    contraMatch = ismember(contra, usuariosInfo);
    if emailMatch == true && contraMatch == true
        loopHome = true;
        while loopHome == true
            fprintf('\n  Login correcto');
            fprintf('\n  Bienvenido a Adidas.com\n');
            fprintf('\n------------------------------------------');
            fprintf('\n    Catalogo verano - 2019');
            fprintf('\n    - 1) Calzado');
            fprintf('\n    - 2) Ropa');
            fprintf('\n    - 3) Accesorios');
            fprintf('\n    - 4) Ir a carrito de compras');
            fprintf('\n    - 5) Log Out');
            fprintf('\n------------------------------------------');
            opc = input('\n    Selecciona la opcion que quieras revisar:  ');

            switch opc
                case 1 %En case 1 entra a categoria de calzado
                    loopCalidad = true;
                    while loopCalidad == true
                        fprintf('\n    Calzados Adidas verano - 2019');
                        opc = input('\n    Selecciona la calidad del producto (3 = Premium | 2 = ProQuality | 1 = Standar):');
                        if opc == 3 %Opcion Premium
                            %Este bloque nos permite ver y seleccionar los
                            %elementos que queremos que esten dentro de nuestro
                            %carrito de compras
                            fprintf('\n    -----------------------------');
                            fprintf('\n    | CALIDAD PREMIUM)');
                            %Primera opcion - https://www.adidas.mx/tenis-nite-jogger/CG6098.html
                            fprintf('\n    -----------------------------');
                            fprintf('\n    | Opcion 1)');
                            fprintf('\n    | TENIS NITE JOGGER');
                            fprintf('\n    | Calidad: 3 / Premium');
                            fprintf('\n    | Precio: $2,999');
                            %Segunda opcion - https://www.adidas.mx/tenis-falcon/CG6210.html
                            fprintf('\n    -----------------------------');
                            fprintf('\n    | Opcion 2)');
                            fprintf('\n    | TENIS FALCON');
                            fprintf('\n    | Calidad: 3 / Premium');
                            fprintf('\n    | Precio: $1,999');
                            %Tercera opcion - https://www.adidas.mx/tenis-micropacer-stan-smith-raf-simons/EE7950.html
                            fprintf('\n    -----------------------------');
                            fprintf('\n    | Opcion 3)');
                            fprintf('\n    | TENIS MICROPACER STAN SMITH RAF SIMONS');
                            fprintf('\n    | Calidad: 3 / Premium');
                            fprintf('\n    | Precio: $6,499');
                            %Cuarta opcion - Salir
                            fprintf('\n    -----------------------------');
                            fprintf('\n    | Opcion 4)');
                            fprintf('\n    | Regresar');
                            fprintf('\n    -----------------------------');
                            opc = input('\n    Selecciona la opcion que quieras comprar:  ');

                            switch opc
                                case 1
                                    fprintf('\n    Confirmando compra: "TENIS NITE JOGGER"');
                                    opc = input('\n    (1 = Confirmar compra | 2 = Cancelar compra)"');
                                    if opc == 1
                                        newRow = ["TENIS NITE JOGGER","$2,999"];
                                        recibo = [recibo; newRow];
                                        totalCompra = totalCompra + 2999;
                                    end
                                    break;
                                case 2
                                    fprintf('\n    Confirmando compra: "TENIS FALCON"');
                                    opc = input('\n    (1 = Confirmar compra | 2 = Cancelar compra)"');
                                    if opc == 1
                                        newRow = ["TENIS FALCON","$1,999"];
                                        recibo = [recibo; newRow];
                                        totalCompra = totalCompra + 1999;
                                    end
                                    break;
                                case 3
                                    fprintf('\n    Confirmando compra: "TENIS MICROPACER STAN SMITH RAF SIMONS"');
                                    opc = input('\n    (1 = Confirmar compra | 2 = Cancelar compra)"');
                                    if opc == 1
                                        newRow = ["TENIS MICROPACER STAN SMITH RAF SIMONS","$6,499"];
                                        recibo = [recibo; newRow];
                                        totalCompra = totalCompra + 6499;
                                    end
                                    break;
                                case 4
                                    loopCalidad = false;
                                    break;
                                otherwise
                                    fprintf('\n      *Selecciona una opcion correcta');
                                break;
                            end
                        elseif opc == 2 %Opcion ProQuality

                        elseif opc == 1 %Opcion Standar

                        else
                        end
                    end


                    break;
                case 2 %En case 2 entra a categoria de ropa

                    break;
                case 3 %En case 3 entra a categoria de accesorios

                    break;
                case 4 %En case 4 entra a carrito de compras

                    break;
                case 5 %En case 5 se deslogea
                    loopHome = false;
                    break;
                otherwise
                    fprintf('\n    *Selecciona una opcion correcta');
                    break;
            end
        end
    else
        fprintf('\n  Login incorrecto\n');
        opcion = input('  *Deseas repetir de nuevo la operacion? (1 = si | 2 = no)\n');
        if opcion == 2
            loopMain = false;
        end
    end 
 end
```

Comment: Comprueba el estado de las variables al empezar

Comment: El problema está en el break, que sirve para salir de bucles (del switch se sale sin necesidad de break). Así que cada vez que haya un break, se saldrá del bucle en el que se encuentre.

Comment: Debes cambiar el `break` para poder `continue`